# GRPC C++ client finish() blocks forever with Golang server

Tags: c++, go, grpc

I have a C++ gRPC client and Golang gRPC server. For a bi-directional stream, when the client wants to close the stream, it blocks forever on the call to Finish().

This only happens if there is **no error**, that is, the server rpc function returns `nil`. If the server was written in C++, I understand it would have returned `Status::Ok`.

If the Golang server returns a non-nil error, then the Finish() function returns as expected. The problem occurs only in the case of no error.

**Example:**

*.proto*

```
service StreamTest {
  rpc Get(stream StreamCommand) returns (stream Result) {}
}
message StreamCommand{
  string cmd = 1;
}
message Result {
  string res = 1;
}
```

*.cpp*

```
std::unique_ptr<ClientReaderWriter<StreamCommand, Result>> readerWriter;
bool Get(Result &res) {
    return readerWriter->Read(&res);
}

bool CloseClient() {
    StreamCommand cmd;
    cmd.set_cmd("stop");
    readerWriter->Write(cmd);
    readerWriter->WritesDone();
    Status status = readerWriter->Finish(); // <------ BLOCKING
    return status.ok();
}
```

I have tested the server with a Golang gRPC client and it works fine. Should the server return something other than a `nil` error? Should I report this as a bug?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share your server code ?

Comment: Had the same issue recently, reading all remaining messages before calling `Finish()` helped.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with Go, but I know c++ layer. Can you run the client with GRPC_VERBOSITY=debug and GRPC_TRACE=api? That would give more insight into the problem.